# How to make an script open at login?

Tags: shell, login, autostart

I have an app like `top` that I want to open it when login.

Example: My Debian starts at the CLI with auto-login, and then, automatically the `top` shows up.

It is an analogue of having a GUI desktop that opens a `LXPanel` or a browser automatically with fullscreen. However, with the CLI and a command line app.

How can I do that? Just appending `top` at the end of `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want that but yes if you put it in your bash profile it will open at login.  Just make sure your .bashrc file isn't sourcing your bash profile.

Comment: @Jesse_b It worked!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the procedure is for `gnome-terminal`, but you can install `xterm` and easily achieve the expected result.

`apt-get install xterm`

Then setting the following wherever your autostart stuff goes; for example, one of these places, depending on your Desktop Environment or x server startup procedure

`~/.local/share/autostart/
~/.config/autostart/
~/.kde/Autostart/`

Add this to a startup file in one of those directories

`xterm -e top &`